# Use CMS blocks inside product attributes

Tags: magento2.2, event-observer, product-attribute, template-directive

I want to use CMS blocks inside product attributes, eg in description and short description.

- inside product description I've added `{{block id="test1"}}`.
- i have two observer

  - `catalog_product_collection_load_after` for collections
  - `catalog_controller_product_view` for products

Observer:

```
public function execute(Observer $observer): void
{
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $this->helper->parse($product);
}
```

Helper:

```
use Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider
...
public function __construct(Context $context, FilterProvider $filterProvider)
{
    $this->filterProvider = $filterProvider;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function parse(Product $product): void
{
    # some code to get attribute code and value
    ...
    $attributeValue = $this->insertCmsBlocks($product, $attributeCode, $attributeValue);
    $product->setData($attributeCode, $attributeValue);
}

public function insertCmsBlocks(Product $product, string $attributeCode, string $attributeValue): string
{
    ...
    $attributeValue = $this->filterProvider->getBlockFilter()->filter($attributeValue);
    ...

    return $attributeValue;
}
```

---

#### Category page

This works w/o any problems ...

[image]

---

#### Product page

Instead of default LUMA theme product page "compare" and "wishlist" block is loaded ...

[image]

---

- `block_html` and `full_page` is disabled ...
- `$this->filterProvider->getBlockFilter()->filter($attributeValue)` looks ok when debugging

[image]

If I comment `$this->filterProvider->getBlockFilter()->filter($attributeValue)` everthing works ... so, there is no problem with the event, cache or `$product->setData()` ...

**Any ideas whats wrong with this code?**

Comment: I have tried with the same observer you wrote and it worked for me. Where on your image should be the description displayed? Because I can not see it anywhere. Have you tried debugging on `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description::getProduct` and what does the description holds? Maybe it's changed to default somewhere. And last thing, you cleared the cache right? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me suggest a slightly different way of processing the attributes on the product pages that I think might be better. The core uses the `\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output` class to process them and it has an `addHandler()` method. It takes a class as a callback and executes a method on it, allowing your code to be very clean. So instead of using an event, add a plugin:

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output"> 
    <plugin name="Example::attribute_handler" type="Example\Module\Plugin\Product\AttributeHandler"/>
</type>
```

Add the product attribute handler (this can be used for category attributes too) and inject your helper into the constructor. The product attribute handlers need an arbitrary name, as you [can see in the method definition](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Helper/Output.php#L95).

```
namespace Example\Module\Plugin\Product;

class AttributeHandler
{
    private $attributeHandler;

    public function __construct(\Example\Module\Model\Processor\Attribute\Handler $attributeHandler)
    {
        $this->attributeHandler = $attributeHandler;
    }

    public function beforeProductAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output $context, $subject)
    {
        if (count($context->getHandlers('productattribute')) < 1) {
            $context->addHandler('productAttribute', $this->attributeHandler);
        }
    }
}
```

Last, update your helper to include a `productAttribute()` method. I like to check for the existence of a substring `{{` before running the processor to make it more efficient if there is not blocks / widgets.

The `productAttribute()` method would look like this in your case (I would abstract `insertCmsBlocks()` further to include a method that does not require `Product`):

```
public function productAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output $context, $value, $params)
{
    if ($value && strpos((string) $value, '{{') !== false) {
        $value = $this->filter($value);
    }

    return $value;
}
```

One benefit of this approach is that it works anywhere the Magento_Catalog product attribute handler is used.

Comment: It works. Thank you. I'll leave the question open until bounty ends ... maybe someone has an idea whats breaks the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using FPC?
The `catalog_controller_product_view` event cannot be used in conjunction with FPC cache since Magento will not raise it after the first visit.

See here for a [possible](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116450/magento-is-caching-catalog-controller-product-view-event?rq=1) solution

Comment: No. FPC is disabled.

Comment: @sv3n can you confirm that your observer is getting hit on every product page view?

Comment: Yes. I've updated the question ... w/o `$this->filterProvider....` everything is OK.

Comment: what happens if you log `$product->getData($attributeCode, $attributeValue);`  after `$product->setData($attributeCode, $attributeValue);` does the value for the attribute include your CMS block?

Comment: `getData()` looks correct. Thanks for trying to help, but bassplayer7 answer looks good to me.

Comment: @sv3n  bassplayer7's answer is a good other method, I'm trying to figure out what is it about your code that breaks the layout of the product page