# Get current product id in Observer controller_front_send_response_before

Tags: magento2, event-observer

`catalog_controller_product_view` event cannot be used in conjunction with **FPC cache** since Magento will not raise it after the first visit. That's why I am using `controller_front_send_response_before` observer as it is described in:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/126377/31910

My question is, **how can I get current product id in this observer?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main idea is use a request for your purposes. There is a two cases: path without an url rewrite and with url rewrite. Here is a sample code which parse path from request and obtain a product id:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

/**
 * Class ResponseBefore
 *
 */
class ResponseBefore implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Product
     */
    private $productUrlRewriteResource;

    /**
     * ResponseBefore constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Product $productUrlRewriteResource
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Product $productUrlRewriteResource
    ) {
        $this->productUrlRewriteResource = $productUrlRewriteResource;
    }

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request */
        $request = $observer->getRequest();

        // Check is we are on the product page

        if ($request->getParam('id')) {
            // Regular request like `catalog/product/view/id/8`
            $id = $request->getParam('id');
        } else {
            // In case url rewrite we should search id in the `url_rewrite` table by path and type
            /** @var string $pathInfo */
            $pathInfo         = $request->getPathInfo();
            $preparedPathInfo = ltrim(trim($pathInfo), "/");

            $connection = $this->productUrlRewriteResource->getConnection();
            $table      = $this->productUrlRewriteResource->getTable('url_rewrite');
            $select     = $connection->select();
            $select->from($table, ['entity_id'])
                   ->where('entity_type = :entity_type')
                   ->where('request_path LIKE :request_path');

            $result = $connection->fetchCol(
                $select,
                ['entity_type' => 'product', 'request_path' => $preparedPathInfo]
            );
            $id     = isset($result[0]) ? $result[0] : null;
        }

        // Do something here with parsed id

        return;
    }
}
```

It's not a complete code, but it should help you to write what a you want.

Comment: It worked. Thanks. After product cached using Full page cache, registry was not working, but from your code I am able to get product. :)

Comment: @ShoaibMunir I'm glad to help You :)

Comment: @ShoaibMunir be careful with that kind of code, because it can lead to errors in much cases, like enable store codes in url, custom url-rewrites etc.

Answer (score 2):

Istead of the observer you can use the following method to get the detail of current product

```
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class yourclassname
{
    /**
     * @var Registry
     */

    protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(Registry $registry)
    {
            $this->_registry = $registry;
    }

    public yourfunction()
    {
        $currentProduct = $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
        //to get id
        $productId=$currentProduct->getId();
        //do rest of your work
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@mohith your code is fine if your using magento 2.2.x. Registry has been deprecated in Magento 2.3.x.

Use Magento/Catalog/Model/Session in Magento Latest version to get the current product.

Comment: Thanks @Venugopal :)